# The wordy cheerleader squad

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

> Give me an AT! A british insult maybe?
>   Give me an IS! Strong winds and a jumbler of tongues and body parts?
>   Give me an EE! A Mansfield venue now a cable plan?

Give me an IT! What am I?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're

> TWITTER!

This one works on a similar premise to "reverse hangman" puzzles: in order, you were a

> twATter (a British insult is "twat"), twISter (tornados, the party game, and tongue twisters), and twEEter (old name for Mansfield Xfinity center).

Comment: Yup good job. As expected, it didn't take long for someone to get it